Stop Exasol sessions with sqlalchemy+django queries
I have Django endpoint that retrieves data from Exasol DB using SQLalchemy.
It looks as simple as this:
@api_view(['GET'])
def exasol_data_view(request):
    ***
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    
    with Session() as session:
        result = session.execute(query)
        data = result.fetchall()
        session.close()

I want to implement a feature where the system cancels a request whenever the user calls the same endpoint repeatedly. This will prevent Exasol from accumulating a large queue of pending requests when a user repeatedly clicks the 'request' button.
I tried multiple options including session.close(), close_all_sessions(), and so on. Additionally, engine.pool.status() always returns info that I have only 1 connection.
PS: I'm not allowed to send raw SQL request with KILL SESSION.
